# Caching an LDAP connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, ldap, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on an internal portal that allows users to request accounts to various other domains we manage.

I have to check if a certain account already exists via LDAP, so this is what I do to make a connection.

```
const string server = "ldap.mydomain.net:636";
using (var ldapSSLConn = new LdapConnection(server))
{
    var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("user", "supersecurepassword");
                        ldapSSLConn.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
                        ldapSSLConn.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
                        ldapSSLConn.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
                        ldapSSLConn.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback((con, cer) => true);
                        ldapSSLConn.Bind(networkCredential);

   // Search happens here
   // Return results

}
```

I can then use the `ldapSSLConn` to search for existing accounts.

Everytime I need to make a connection, it takes me +/- 20 seconds, the search itself 85ms.

Is there a way I can cache the connection? For example open it on `Application_Start()`, and then reference it when I need it?

Comment: *Making* a connection should definitely not take 20 seconds. You might want to debug that first.

Comment: That's because the server is geographically pretty far and it takes a while to establish the TCP-connection. Not much I can do about that.

Comment: Are you sure? 20 seconds almost feels if a dns lookup fails or a route is dead. Or is it on a vpn that needs to start first?

Comment: While I agree with the others, there must be something wrong, there are several LDAP proxy cache engines available. Here is just one http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin23/proxycache.html which may or may not be the correct one for your situation.

Comment: 2 sleeping VPN tunnels (needs to reconnect after x idle time). I'm not in a position where I can make changes to the infrastructure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me.

I'm checking if a connection is cached now, with;

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["LDAPConnection"] == null)
```

If it isn't, I make a connection (see question), and at the end, cache it:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("LDAPConnection", ldapSSLConn, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(8), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.High, null);
```